# How to create actual keyboard strokes in C# (not using InputSimulator)

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendkeys

I'm trying to develop a proof of concept to demonstrate the Metasploit keylogging module to a client. Once a machine has been compromised, this module can be used to record all keystrokes from users of the machine.

I made a script that utilised InputSimulator to create virtual keystrokes; however, whilst this wrote the strings to an open text editor, the keylogging module didn't capture any of them. To me, this thus suggests the keylogging module hooks directly into the keyboard driver.

I'm therefore looking for some C# functionality which will interface directly with the keyboard driver to create these keystrokes that can be captured.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: _[A hook is a mechanism by which an application can intercept events, such as messages, mouse actions, and keystrokes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)_.  Note: Things changed with Vista+ where things got very security conscious.  An app at one level may not be able to capture a process running at an elevated level

Comment: You could use [the free AutoIt library](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to make this quite easy. It has a .Net dll you can use.

Comment: Thanks both. @Micky, do you have any code samples where input is simulated? All I can find are examples where it's keyboard/mouse activity are being monitored.

Comment: @Jingo You'll find that in the link.  The concept is called _journalling_